# Error: Illegal output or inout port connection

Tags: verilog, simulation

```
module stimulus;
    reg [511:0]FROM_LS;
    reg CLOCK;
    reg [2:0]HMIC_CTRL;
    reg [20:0]BRANCH_CTRL;
    reg  [63:0]TO_IF_ID;
    reg FLUSH_CTRL;
    reg [20:0]TO_LS;
        
    // setup clock
    initial
     begin
            inst_line_buf ILB(FLUSH_CTRL,TO_LS,FROM_LS,CLOCK,HMIC_CTRL,BRANCH_CTRL,TO_IF_ID);

      #10 CLOCK = ~CLOCK;
  
    // apply stimulus
  
      FROM_LS[511:480]= 32'b00011_00000_00100_01100_11100_10111_01;
      FROM_LS[479:448]=32'b000_11000_00100_01111_11111_00011_1000;
  
      HMIC_CTRL[2:0]=3'b000;
      BRANCH_CTRL[20:0]=20'b00000_00000_00000_00000;
      #2 $display("FLUSH CONTROL=%b, TO_LS= %b",FLUSH_CTRL,TO_LS);
    end
endmodule
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
# Loading work.inst_line_buf
# ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): [PCDPC] - Port size (512 or 512) does not match connection size (1) for port 'from_LS'. The port definition is at: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/inst_line_buf.v(1).
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): [PCDPC] - Port size (1 or 1) does not match connection size (21) for port 'clk'. The port definition is at: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/inst_line_buf.v(2).
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): [PCDPC] - Port size (3 or 3) does not match connection size (512) for port 'hmic_ctrl'. The port definition is at: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/inst_line_buf.v(3).
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): [PCDPC] - Port size (21 or 21) does not match connection size (1) for port 'branch_ctrl'. The port definition is at: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/inst_line_buf.v(4).
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Error: (vsim-3053) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): Illegal output or inout port connection for "port 'to_if_id'".
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): [PCDPC] - Port size (64 or 64) does not match connection size (3) for port 'to_if_id'. The port definition is at: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/inst_line_buf.v(5).
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Error: (vsim-3053) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): Illegal output or inout port connection for "port 'flush_ctrl'".
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): [PCDPC] - Port size (1 or 1) does not match connection size (21) for port 'flush_ctrl'. The port definition is at: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/inst_line_buf.v(6).
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Error: (vsim-3053) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): Illegal output or inout port connection for "port 'to_LS'".
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/stimulus_ilb.v(10): [PCDPC] - Port size (21 or 21) does not match connection size (64) for port 'to_LS'. The port definition is at: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0a/examples/inst_line_buf.v(7).
#         Region: /stimulus/ILB
# Error loading design
```

Comment: At least show us the warning messages!

Comment: @marty : I have included the code for testbench and also the error as uasked. Can you please help me out to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you show us the full error message, and your `vsim` command line and some relevant Verilog code, all we can offer is a suggestion to Google your error message.

For example, from [modelsim_FAQ](http://www.actel.com/documents/modelsim_FAQ.pdf):

> ModelSim Simulation options have not
>   been set properly (Project Settings >
>   ModelSim > Options) Make the following
>   changes: Right-click the Simulation
>   tab in the Project Flow window or
>   select Project > Settings > Simulation
>   Testbench module name: specify your
>   testbench module name Top level
>   instance name in the testbench:
>   instance name of the DUT Please see
>   the screenshot below for an example.

Update:  Now that you have added some code, the `ILB` looks suspicious.  You use it 1st as an instance name for the `inst_line_buf` module, then you use it again in the `initial` block as what looks like a function or task call.  My guess is that you want it outside of the `initial` block, but with port connections:

```
inst_line_buf ILB (FROM_LS,CLOCK,HMIC_CTRL,TO_IF_ID,FLUSH_CTRL,TO_LS);
```